# Oracle SOA Suite 12c Infrastructure Management Java API change

Tags: oracle-soa

I have developed Java/Groovy scripts utilizing the 11g version of the Oracle Fusion Middleware Java API for Oracle SOA Suite Infrastructure Management:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e10659/toc.htm

However, after checking the 12c version, I found out that the API contains just a small subset of the 11g version of the product:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/soasuite/api-reference-soa/toc.htm

I miss interfaces like Composite, Service, Reference and many others (e.g. from oracle.soa.management.facade). The 11g version offered rich API for querying and managing SCA composites, which is not the case in 12c anymore.

Can you please advise how do you programatically retrieve information about the composites in 12c version?

I could not find any statement from Oracle about this change, if you know more, can you please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from Oracle regarding the API change.

Oracle decided not to document the SOA Suite mgmt API in 12c, so that customers would not be encouraged to use it. The reason behind is that Enterprise Manager provides all the functionality.

I can see a big difference between using automated administration scripts and tedious manual work in EM. That is a different viewpoint of a user-customer and a vendor.